# USB controller will not work in Pygame

Tags: python, controller, usb, pygame, joystick

I have a USB controller that I have mapped to be the arrow keys on the keyboard, outside of gaming programs (as in, you can use it as the normal arrow keys on the keyboard). I did this using the program ControlMK. My Pygame program will not recognize the controller as the keyboard. When I try to use the Joystick modules, the program does not function properly.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
try:
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.init()
    pygame.mixer.init(size=8, buffer=2048)

    pygame.mixer.get_init

except:
    print "error in init\n"

white=(255,255,255)

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.RESIZABLE)

class Loadsound:

    def __init__(self, name, key, sound_file):
        self.name = name
        self.name=key
        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)

sound_left=[]
sound_left.append(Loadsound("left","K_LEFT", "left.wav"))
sound_right=[]
sound_right.append(Loadsound("right","K_RIGHT", "right.wav"))
sound_up=[]
sound_up.append(Loadsound("up","K_UP","up.wav")) 
sound_down=[]
sound_down.append(Loadsound("down","K_DOWN","down.wav"))


while True:
  for i in pygame.event.get():
   if i.type==QUIT:
    exit()
  pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()


  if pressed[K_LEFT]:
      for left in sound_left:
          left.sound.play()
  elif pressed[K_RIGHT]:
      for right in sound_right:
          right.sound.play()
  elif pressed[K_UP]:
      for up in sound_up:
          up.sound.play()
  elif pressed[K_DOWN]:
      for down in sound_down:
          down.sound.play()
```

Thank you for the help!

Edit:

I have been trying to use the Joystick module. Here is where I was taking example code from:

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Joystick_analyzer

I edited my code to include some of it, but it still does not work. Here is my edited code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import *

# set up pygame
try:
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.init()
    pygame.mixer.init(size=8, buffer=2048)

    pygame.mixer.get_init

except:
    print "error in init\n"

white=(255,255,255)

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.RESIZABLE)

class Loadsound:

    def __init__(self, name, key, sound_file):
        self.name = name
        self.name=key
        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)

sound_left=[]
sound_left.append(Loadsound("left","K_LEFT", "left.wav"))
sound_right=[]
sound_right.append(Loadsound("right","K_RIGHT", "right.wav"))
sound_up=[]
sound_up.append(Loadsound("up","K_UP","up.wav")) 
sound_down=[]
sound_down.append(Loadsound("down","K_DOWN","down.wav"))

def __init__(self):
    pygame.joystick.init()
    self.my_joystick = None
    self.joystick_names = []

    for i in range(0, pygame.joystick.get_count()):
        self.joystick_names.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i).get_name())

    print self.joystick_names

    if (len(self.joystick_names) > 0):
        self.my_joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        self.my_joystick.init()

    #max_joy = max(self.my_joystick.get_numaxes(), self.my_joystick.get_numbuttons(), self.my_joystick.get_numhats()

while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.pump()
    if i.type==QUIT:
        exit()
    #pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    #Joystick.init()
    pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #pressed_j=Joystick.get_hat()
    def check_hat(self, p_hat):
        if (self.my_joystick):
            if (p_hat,self.my_joystick.get_numhats()):
                return self.my_joystick.get_hat(p_hat)

        return (0, 0)



    if check_hat==(-1,0):
    #if pressed[K_LEFT]:
        for left in sound_left:
            left.sound.play()
    elif pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        for right in sound_right:
            right.sound.play()
    elif pressed[K_UP]:
        for up in sound_up:
            up.sound.play()
    elif pressed[K_DOWN]:
        for down in sound_down:
            down.sound.play()
```

For clarity, my code DOES work when using the keyboard. However, it does not translate to the controller which is mapped to the same keys.

Comment: Does your program work with the regular keyboard keys?

Comment: You coult try adding a `pygame.event.pump()` call in your main loop

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Pygame's [Joystick module](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html), or something similar, which has method's such as: `Joystick.get_init()`, which tells if the joystick is initialized in Pygame, and `Joystick.get_axis(axis_number)` which returns the Joystick's position, as a float, along a given axis `axis_number`. ControlMK is likely mapping the joystick to key inputs at too high of a level to interact with Pygame, though there may be some way to change that, its documentation seems limited.

Comment: I have been trying to use the Joystick module, but it will not work. I tried following a tutorial on the pygame website about it, but the code in it doesn't work. Here is the link to the code I was looking at:

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Joystick_analyzer

Unfortunately, it gives me syntax errors. I tried implementing parts of it that weren't riddled with syntax in my code, but it wouldn't work, still. I will edit my original post to include this new code.

Comment: ok, this is going to be interactive help, should you choose to accept it: 
1) plug in your USB joystick
2) start python interpreter (simply type `python` in the linux/Mac terminal, or do the same in the windows CMD)
3) type `import pygame`
4) type `pygame.joystick.init()`
5) type `Joystick.get_numaxes` which should tell us which "numbers" the axes are assigned
6) hold the joystick diagonally and type `Joystick.get_axis(axis_number)` for each axes, while holding it

If it returns 0 for each, that's bad, and we'll have to troubleshoot that. Otherwise...

Comment: Well, I started trying to do that, and the same problem arose as before. It complains about the name Joystick not being defined.

Comment: Hmmm. How did you install Pygame? Try installing it with the package manager. It sounds like unfortunately you didn't install all of Pygame, as Joystick is one of the contained modules.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
print "Joystics: ", pygame.joystick.get_count()
my_joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
my_joystick.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print my_joystick.get_axis(0),  my_joystick.get_axis(1) 
        clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit ()
```